# How to use ts-nameof with create-react-app or craco?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, craco, ts-nameof

I want to use [ts-nameof](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof) in my React app created with `create-react-app`. How can I do that without ejection?
Hint: I also use [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco), so a solution involving craco would be also fine for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to achieve with [babel-macro](https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-macros/blob/main/other/docs/user.md#using-with-create-react-app) called [ts-nameof.macro](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof/tree/master/packages/ts-nameof.macro) without ejecting.

I've tested on fresh application generated with:

```sh
npx create-react-app temp --template typescript
```

```sh
# install macro dependecies
yarn add -D ts-nameof.macro
# or
# npm i --save-dev ts-nameof.macro
```

> NOTE: if your react-scripts version lower than 2.0, you also need to install `babel-plugin-macros` as dev dependency.

Update *App.tsx*

```
import React from 'react';
import nameof from "ts-nameof.macro"; // import nameof
import logo from './logo.svg';

import './App.css';

function App() {
  console.log(nameof(window.alert)) // "alert"
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thank for this great reply, bounty awarded! btw, the linked babel-macro docs state that create-react-app already comes with babel-macro, can only confirm that - I didn't have to install it :-)

Comment: I've added it to answer because wasn't sure about your react-scripts version. Yes, if you have higher than 2.0 you don't need that.

Comment: Updated answer with note. Thanks 